# Add python AI script to reactJS

Tags: python, reactjs, artificial-intelligence

So I'm trying to fetch a little script I just made in python, is an OCR, using tesseract module. This is

```
import cv2 
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('plot.png')

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Users/berna/Desktop/Programming/AI_ML_DL/Projects/OCRApp_phototext/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

The problem is that This script need an input image, as you can see the "plot.png".
I know how to connect flask server to reactJS, but how can I do this.
**In ReactJS, enter the image, the script take it, And pass the print value to ReactJS**

Comment: Use an `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`, put a change handler on it, look at `event.target.files`, use `fetch()` with `FormData` to upload the image to your Flask server, do your Tesseract thing, return a JSON response to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
  const sendFile = (file) => {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

    var data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', input.files[0])

    fetch('/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
  };
```

Now after upload just save it on `/tmp` and use it in your script and delete after if you want.

Comment: Okey, I understand it, but I'm new so I don't understand what does /tmp means

Comment: and, the sendFile function, do I need to put it in the input html tag?

Comment: YESS, I already solve it. I add onChange, and then a request in python script with POST method